# Error accessing python class instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting an error when accessing class instance variable and assigning them. When i use format function to convert the instance variable value it is working good.

Code which is throwing error:

```
task.update({
    'email': self.email,
```

Error

```
raise ValueError('Unknown protobuf attr type', type(val))
ValueError: ('Unknown protobuf attr type', <class 'tuple'>)
```

Code which works when using format function:

```
logger.log_text('email {}'.format(self.email))
```

Creation of class instance

```
user = User(post_data)
user.create()
```

Class

```
class User(object):
""" User Model for storing user related details """
__tablename__ = 'Users'

def __init__(self, data, admin=False):
    bcrypt = Bcrypt()
    self.email = data.get('email'),
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
        data.get('email'), 12
    ).decode()
    self.is_admin = admin
    self.firstname = "firstname"
    self.middlename = "middlename"
    self.lastname = "lastname"
    self.address = "address"
    self.is_active = True
    self.ds = datastore.Client()

def create(self):
    """
    Create User
    :return: string
    """
    logger.log_text("create user")
    with self.ds.transaction():
        incomplete_key = self.ds.key(self.__tablename__)
        task = datastore.Entity(key=incomplete_key)
        task.update({
            'email': self.email,
            'password': '{}'.format(self.password)
        })
        self.ds.put(task)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very easy mistake to make: There is a stray comma on this line:

```
self.email = data.get('email'),
```

which is turning `self.email` into a tuple. For example:

```
>>> a = 'hi'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> b = 'hi',
>>> type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
```